# online SQL editor (or not) that capitalizes automatically the sql commands (example SELECT, AND, THEN, DISTINCT, DROP....)

Tags: mysql, sql, editor, text-editor

I have a big query which is all written in small letters.

1. Is there any way to automatic switch only the commands in capital without editing them manually?
2. Also If can auto alignment the text would be helpful too.

Comment: http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: I think SQL syntax highlighter is more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many Online Editors are available

After Googling for `online sql formatter` I found this useful

http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

If you want IDE then this would be best option, [Toad](http://www.quest.com/toad/)

Answer (score 0):

[phpMyAdmin](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/) capitalizes MySQL commands and add line-breaks, but doesn't indent nested selects or joins.

Answer (score 0):

[SQLyog](http://www.webyog.com/en/) does capitalisation, can't remember about indenting